# Entity Framework Core Issue with DbContextFactory affecting performance in Blazor application

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

The app works as intended after changing from a single DBContext to DbContextFactory, but performance of the app has suffered, causing input lag throughout the app that wasn't there when using a long-lived data context. Has anyone experienced similar issues, and have you found ways around this?

```
   builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DBContext>(
        options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")),
        ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Sorry if there isn't enough detail here, but from what I've read, DbContextFactory is the proper way to call DB Contexts in Entity Framework Core using Blazor. Originally, had all of the data being pulled from a single scoped DBContext instance. In an attempt to resolve some concurrency issues we were having, I switched all of my db call to create a new context with every unit of work and dispose it once I have finished using it.

```
DBContext _ContextInstance = _DBContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
ContextInstance.Dispose();
```

I know by default, DbContextFactory is a Singlton service, I changed them all to scoped to work with all of our other scoped service. The strange thing is it ran fine locally before this change, but then when threw errors about a scoped service trying to consume a singleton.

Here is an example of a method that is running slow, it doesn't seem like something that should take 3-4 seconds to run (side note-This runs twice as fast on my machine in VS2022 debugger):

```
public List<VMRAMarginDetail> GetFilteredProjects(FilterRef FilterRef, List<int> ProjectIds)
        {

            if (ProjectIds != null)
            {
                List<VMRAMarginDetail> FilteredProjects = new();
                var dateFilterValue = Convert.ToDateTime(FilterRef.MonthEnding);


                using (MarginReportAppContext _MRAInstance = _MRAFactory.CreateDbContext())
                {
                    FilteredProjects = _MRAInstance.V_MRA_MarginDetails.Where(a => a.MonthEnding == dateFilterValue && ProjectIds.Contains(a.ProjectId)).ToList();
                }

                if (FilterRef.Region != null && FilterRef.Region.Length > 0)
                {
                    //filter by region desc
                    FilteredProjects = FilteredProjects.Where(a => a.Region.ToUpper() == FilterRef.Region.ToUpper() && a.Group.ToUpper() == FilterRef.Group.ToUpper() && a.Division.ToUpper() == FilterRef.Division).ToList();
                }
                else if (FilterRef.Group != null && FilterRef.Group.Length > 0)
                {
                    //filter by group desc
                    FilteredProjects = FilteredProjects.Where(a => a.Group.ToUpper() == FilterRef.Group.ToUpper() && a.Division.ToUpper() == FilterRef.Division).ToList();
                }
                else if (FilterRef.Division != null && FilterRef.Division.Length > 0)
                {
                    //filter by division desc
                    FilteredProjects = FilteredProjects.Where(a => a.Division.ToUpper() == FilterRef.Division).ToList();
                }

                if (FilterRef.MprApprover != null && FilterRef.MprApprover.Length > 0)
                {
                    //filter by mpr approver
                    FilteredProjects = FilteredProjects.Where(a => a.MPRApprover == FilterRef.MprApprover).ToList();
                }

                if (FilterRef.Company != null && FilterRef.Company.Length > 0)
                {
                    //filter by company
                    FilteredProjects = FilteredProjects.Where(a => a.CompanyName == FilterRef.Company).ToList();
                }

                return FilteredProjects;
            }
            else
            {
                return new();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you have changed singleton to scoped?  It erases benefits of factory.

Comment: Agreed, a scoped service should have no issue consuming a Singleton, there would be an exception if a Singleton attempted to use a scoped service. More detail I think is needed about any exception when the factory is a Singleton. More info will be needed to address this input lag. For instance, do you have lazy loading proxies enabled?

Comment: @StevePy Thanks for the info, I will try to change the service back to Singleton. The reason I did this was it is being used in a scoped service, I tied to make the services consuming the contextfactory Singleton after the fact but kept getting exceptions that the context itself was a scoped service even though it wasn't defined in the Program.cs. So I manually added them as singletons. Then it stared failing on JS interops being a Scoped service. I may just need to fiddle around with the app a bit more. I will post again if I learn anything new.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I will look into this as well, I could only at mention one person. I don't post here much because I usually figure things out on my own, haha. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I've switched my DBContextFactory services back to singleton. The app is working just fine, but there is still latency when calling data. You would thing 250 records filtered with a where clause using linq wouldn't be that taxing, but maybe I'm still missing something. We are using Telerik UI controls if that means anything.

Comment: @StevePy AddDbContextFactory doesn't have .UseLazyLoadingProxies() as an option

Comment: @StevePy - After a little research I can say we are not using LazyLoading on any of the context instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looking at the query in question there is definitely some optimization you should consider:

```
using (MarginReportAppContext _MRAInstance = _MRAFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    FilteredProjects = _MRAInstance.V_MRA_MarginDetails.Where(a => a.MonthEnding == dateFilterValue && ProjectIds.Contains(a.ProjectId)).ToList();
}
```

The above is loading all projects for the date filter and project ID into memory, then performing the remaining filtering in memory. Depending on how many records that might be, this could be pretty expensive. Assuming your database collation is case insensitive, this method can be simplified considerably and optimized to build a query against the database rather than loading the larger set into memory:

```
public List<VMRAMarginDetail> GetFilteredProjects(FilterRef FilterRef, List<int> ProjectIds)
{

    if (ProjectIds == null || !ProjectIds.Any())
        return new();


    var dateFilterValue = Convert.ToDateTime(FilterRef.MonthEnding);


    using (MarginReportAppContext _MRAInstance = _MRAFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        var query = _MRAInstance.V_MRA_MarginDetails.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.MonthEnding == dateFilterValue && ProjectIds.Contains(a.ProjectId));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterRef.Region) 
            && FilterRef.Region.Length > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.Region == FilterRef.Region 
                && a.Group == FilterRef.Group 
                && a.Division == FilterRef.Division);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterRef.Group))
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.Group == FilterRef.Group
                && a.Division == FilterRef.Division);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterRef.Division))
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.Division == FilterRef.Division);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterRef.MprApprover))
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.MPRApprover == FilterRef.MprApprover);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterRef.Company))
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.CompanyName == FilterRef.Company);
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

This builds the query to be executed once at the end with the `ToList()` call. Note that if we are returning entities we don't need the DbContext to worry about tracking any loaded references so we add `AsNoTracking()` to the query which will help speed it up a touch. This also assumes the DB is using case insensitive collation so we don't need to worry about the 'ToUpper' in the comparisons. If the database is running case sensitive collation then you would need to explicitly add those.

If this data is going into a data grid, it may also be prudent to project the projects into a ViewModel with just the values the datagrid needs to display.

In that case I'd create a class for the view model with just the Project fields the grid needs to display (and any keys that would be useful, like ProjectId) then change the method signature to return the list of view models and replace the:

```
return query.ToList();
```

with something like:

```
return query.Select(x => new ProjectSummaryViewModel
{
    ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
    // ... set remaining fields
}).ToList();
```

or investigate Automapper and it's `ProjectTo()` method. When using projection with `Select()` or `ProjectTo()` you also do not need to worry about adding `AsNoTracking` as projection does not return entities to be tracked.

Instead of resulting in a query that loads all fields from the table(s), it returns only the fields we need. This can save time & memory, plus can facilitate more optimal indexing in certain situations. (I.e. where we only need a few columns on a query run very often then specific indexes could be set up for those scenarios)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I did end up adding .NoTracking to queries that don't need changes yesterday. It seems to be a little faster, but not quite what we're expecting yet. The query should only be pulling roughly 200 records. I will report back once I've tried some of your other suggestions.

Comment: Another thing I would like to not is that the view was created specifically for the grid, so the fields being pulled are all necessary.

Comment: Seems to work well enough, it makes sense that pulling a new set of records may cause some slowness, I think some of what I was experiencing was just because I was remoting into my work computer.